Check solution to probability ice-cream problem
I'm not sure if I was thinking about the problem correctly and if I am on the right track. I'm looking for an explanation and some intuition on how to approach such problems. I have put my solutions down to show how I interpreted the problems.

An ice cream parlour has the following 4 flavours and 5 toppings options.
How many desserts are possible using one flavour of ice cream and three different toppings? Order is not important here.
$$4\cdot\binom{5}{3} = 4\cdot 10= 40$$
How many desserts are possible using one flavour of ice cream and from zero to five toppings? Order is not important here.
$$4\cdot 2^5 = 128.$$
How many different combinations of flavours of three scoops of ice cream are possible if it is permissible to make all three scoops the same flavour? The order of the flavours is important here.
$$4^3 = 64.$$
This last one, I'm especially not sure about because I read similar problems and solutions online and different approaches were taken. Could I get an intuitive explanation on how these problems should be understood?

In your first answer you seem to imply that you have 5/2 options for choosing three different toppings. This seems like it should be a whole number. Also, usually questions that are just "check my work" questions aren't usually well received on this site.

@Nic I'm looking for an explanation, i just put my solution to show what I tried and see if i'm on the right track and thinking about the problem correctly. Will my question get closed for this?

All of your solutions are correct.  In the last problem, you have four choices for each of the three positions.

You calculated $\binom{5}{3}$ wrong. We have that $\binom{5}{3} = \frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!} = \frac{5 \cdot 4}{2 \cdot 1} = 10$. Otherwise, you're on the right track for every problem.
